# Obter a quantidade de casas decimais de um decimal

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

Como posso fazer para obter a quantidade de casas decimais de uma variável  `decimal`?

Ex.: Se eu receber o número:

> 4.5 - deve retornar **1**
>   5.65 - deve retornar **2**
>   6.997 - deve retornar **3**

Eu sei que tem como fazer convertendo para `string`, algo como:

```
decimal CasasDecimais(decimal arg){
     return arg.ToString().Substring(arg.ToString().LastIndexOf(",") + 1).Length;
}
```

E também já vi [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture) do SOen, mas eu gostaria de receber alternativas a essas duas formas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem soluções mais "elegantes" usando matemática pura, mas seriam bem mais complicadas (alguém pode ficar tentado a fazer uma operação simples e não vai dar certo para todas situações). A mais simples é esta:

```
(3.1415.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Split('.')[1].Length
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NM8zSG). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9KAF8N). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/GetDecimalPart.cs).

> Depois houve uma edição mas para `decimal` o algoritmo é o mesmo.

Comment: Acredito que a solução sempre passa por transformar em strings, porque números de ponto flutuante não conseguem representar valores como 0.2 ou 0.1 de forma exata. Se usar matemática pura, vai encontrar 15 casas decimais porque o valor que o computador enxerga é 0.1999999999999 ou 0.1000000000000001. Arredondar para um número de casas decimais menor que 15 (de acordo com o que a aplicação requer - poderia ser 2, 5, 10...) e verificar onde começam os zeros é uma opção.

Comment: É, na verdade tenho minhas dúvidas se com `double` é possível acertar até mesmo com *string*. Mas a pergunta foi mudada para `decimal`.

Comment: Só tem um detalhe que precisa corrigir neste código, da forma como ele está ele é dependente de configurações do SO para funcionar, exatamente assim ele daria erro na maioria dos computadores em Português Brasileiro já que usam por padrão a vírgula como separador decimal, mas é simples corrigir mudando o `ToString()` para `ToString(CultereInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa você tem razão, editado, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se for apenas por diferentes forma daria para usar um while

```
public static int casasDecimais(decimal d)
{
    int res = 0;
    while(d != (long)d)
    {
        res++;
        d = d*10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zz5Wuu